# After bcrypt the password in laravel i am not able to log in

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, bcrypt, password-hash

Initially i have a plain password but after hashing when i try to login server says These credentials do not match our records.Any help ? here is the code which i used to bcrypt all the user password .

```
$users=UsersModel::get();
    foreach ($users as $users) {
        $users->password = bcrypt($users->password);
     $users->save();

    }
                return $users;
```

Comment: Which version of `laravel` are you using?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/hashing are you verifying the password correctly?

Comment: laravel version 5.4.36

Comment: You may find this php article helpful. It's about password hashing.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php